# Sequelize include related item for polymorphic relation

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

From the [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#scopes) we have a `Comment` model with a polymorphic relation to `Image` and `Post`:

```
this.Comment = this.sequelize.define('comment', {
    title: Sequelize.STRING,
    commentable: Sequelize.STRING,
    commentable_id: Sequelize.INTEGER
});

this.Comment.prototype.getItem = function() {
    return this['get' + this.get('commentable').substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() + this.get('commentable').substr(1)]();
};

this.Post.hasMany(this.Comment, {
    foreignKey: 'commentable_id',
    constraints: false,
    scope: {
        commentable: 'post'
    }
});
this.Comment.belongsTo(this.Post, {
    foreignKey: 'commentable_id',
    constraints: false,
    as: 'post'
});

this.Image.hasMany(this.Comment, {
    foreignKey: 'commentable_id',
    constraints: false,
    scope: {
        commentable: 'image'
    }
});
this.Comment.belongsTo(this.Image, {
    foreignKey: 'commentable_id',
    constraints: false,
    as: 'image'
});
```

Now, how to get a `Comment` with related commentable item? (it can be `Post` or `Image`)

```
Comment.findOne({
    where: {title: 'sequelize'},
    include: ['commentable']  // what should be here?
});
```

Comment: Did you have any success in create with polymorphic association?

Comment: @AnuraagDJain  actually you can't eager load related item with polymorphic BUT you can use prototype function getItem in model to load related item. (lazy load) maybe performance is an issue in this way but take it easy :)

Comment: Ok. I was unable to create comments along with creating posts. SequalizeError I was getting

Comment: I was able to eager load from my polymorphic table.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?? I am running into the same thing... I am loading an entity that has polymorphic relationships to several other objects. Would like to load all of them into the "as" name I use ("asset" in my case).

Answer (score 1):

From the [doc](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#scopes)

> The getItem utility function on Comment completes the picture - it
>   simply converts the commentable string into a call to either getImage
>   or getPost, providing an abstraction over whether a comment belongs to
>   a post or an image. You can pass a normal options object as a
>   parameter to getItem(options) to specify any where conditions or
>   includes.

Reference topic [Sequelize ORM: polymorphic associations 1:m possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50640466/sequelize-orm-polymorphic-associations-1m-possible). I hope this help you out.